# How to tell which powershell V3 cmdlets are supported in Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: powershell-3.0

How do I tell which powershell V3 RC cmdlets will be supported in windows 2008 R2? It is not clear in the help documentation which will be present and on early examination, quite a few appear not to be workable unless working in win 2k12 RC.

If Windows 2008 R2 is not supported for the 2000+ new cmdlets in the RC, then the investment in the bright devops future (see links below) seems unlikely to pay off unless building an entirely new infrastructure. Any existing systems at my shop will take years to migrate entirely and win2k12 will be the exception not the rule I think for the vast majority of shops until quite a few years down the road.

Example cmdlets missing in windows 2008 R2
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh405007(VS.85).aspx

devops overview by Jeff Snover.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowsserver/archive/2012/05/29/windows-server-2012-powershell-3-0-and-devops-part-1.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowsserver/archive/2012/05/29/windows-server-2012-powershell-3-0-and-devops-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address this issue, Microsoft is intending to have all the TechNet information up to date by the time General Release happens. This will include the version of PowerShell any given cmdlet was added to PowerShell. This will cover the native PowerShell Cmdlets - for other cmdlets, it will depend on that project team.

The 2000+ new cmdlets you speak of are NOT all going to be backported to Server 2008/R2. Some cmdlets (eg RSAT) will go down level but for others you'll need Server 2012.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... Thanks for the input. As mentioned, I hope that a variety of the modules are ported downlevel because I'll be stuck with 95% 2008 boxes and 5% 2012 boxes for the next 5 to 10 years (if history is any judge) and doing a lot of great devops automation for the IT team will have little value if it only works for 2012.  
Guess I'll need to just keep my ear to the ground on this one.

Comment: First, PowerShell V3 won't be supported with XP and Server 2003. I think you know that! Also most, if not all of the modules in Server 2013 will NOT be ported down-level. Of course, you can do always remoting into Server 2012 boxes and run V3 cmdlets from there. Depending on what you are doing, it may make sense to upgrade sooner to Server 2012. Sorry if that's not the answer you wanted.